# JodaTime : How to get ISO formatted time from DateTime object?

Tags: android, datetime, jodatime

I'm getting DTO using the Joda:

```
dateTimeObj = new DateTime();
```

I would like to convert this DTO to formatted string in ISO format:

```
2016-03-06T11:30:00-05:00
```

I tried it using the:

```
dateTimeObj = new DateTime().toDateTimeISO();
```

But without the luck.

How can i do it in the right way please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`toDateTimeISO()` is deprecated, use `toDateTime()`
http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Instant.html

Also:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MMMM, yyyy");
String str = fmt.print(dt);
```

See pattern syntax here: 
http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html

Comment: Hm, I don't see how "MMMM, yyyy" matches the desired output "2016-03-06T11:30:00-05:00"?

Comment: @MenoHochschild it doesn't. I provided brief example and link with details. Appropriate pattern is presented in comment below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IsoDateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis()](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#dateTimeNoMillis--) to get a format without millisecond part:

```
 DateTime dt = new DateTime();
 DateTimeFormatter fmt = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis();
 String str = fmt.print(dt);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke the `format` method like this:

```
.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT));
```

Answer (score -1):

First off, you'll need to use a [LocalDateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.html) instead of a DateTime to have access to the timezone in your format.

Use a [DateTimeFormatter](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) with the format defined as in the chart [here](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html).

The format you want will be "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss-ZZZZ".